# Can a VeriFone terminal application communicate via Ethernet, but also store local data?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, verifone

Ideally, I would connect a VeriFone terminal to the Internet via an Ethernet cable and transmit transaction data in real time, but I also want to program the terminal to be able to work in offline mode and save transaction data to a file to transmit later. Is this possible?

I would also like to know how much of the communication is with the processing host vs the merchant services provider's application.

Comment: This is more detailed [than your last question today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8985703/255756), but IMHO still off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but you will need a SDK for that and what goes on or offline depends on your needs. On a Vx510 device you have access to file system, LAN, dial-up or gprs communication, keyboard, printer, display and a lot more.